# Prove by induction any $k$-hypercube (for$ k>1$) has a Hamilton Circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I have a basic understanding of graph theory and I know what a Hamiltonian circuit is, but I really need help with this proof, it makes little since to me. Thanks so much in advance for the help!!

Here is the question: 
Recall the construction of a $k$-dimensional hypercube as a graph. Prove by induction any $k$-hypercude (for $k>1$) has a Hamiltonian circuit.

Hint for induction step: 
Define h2 as a Hamiltonian circuit in the 2 dimensional hypercube. How can you build a Hamiltonian circuit on the 3-hypercube using h2? Take your idea and generalize it to build a Hamiltonian circuit for the k-hypercube given hk-1

Comment: Surely this proof exists elsewhere on the internet and even this site; you should then explain the exact troubles you are having. For instance, can you do the first part of the hint?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have looked everywhere for this proof and I can't find it anywhere. It's very possible that I could have over looked it though. But I'm positive I've been everywhere can't find it. Also I can't do any parts of it really. I'm not sure what it is saying. I don't know if that helps with clarification or not.

Comment: It's unclear whether you have done any work on this, or you are just regurgitating a question you are supposed to do. And by "do", I don't mean "looked everywhere". The question starts with **Recall the construction of a $k$-dimensional hypercube** - what do you recall about that?

Comment: The recall is just a hint to refer to how a k-dimensional hupercube is constructed. And everything I typed is the question I'm suppose to answer.

Comment: Do you in fact recall anything about the construction of a $k$-dimensional hypercube? Do you have any material that could help you recall something useful?

Answer (score 1):

As some starting help, consider the case of moving from a square to a cube (the smallest dimension case for which this holds).

A cube can be seen as two copies of a square, with edges joining the two copies across all the matched vertices.

Then by the induction hypothesis, a Hamiltonian circuit exists on each of the squares. Can you see how to link up those two circuits to make a circuit for the cube?

Comment: Thank you for the help! This did help me start the problem and I was able to get the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another way of using Induction for this problem is as follows. I'll denote the $n+1-$Hypercube by $Q_n$.

We know that $Q_{n+1}$ = $Q_n \square  K_2$. Where $ \square  $ denotes the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of two graphs.

*Base* : for $n=2$, we know that $Q_{2}$ is Hamiltonian.

*Induction* : Suppose that the $Q_{n}$ is Hamiltonian.

Also we know that $K_2$ is Hamiltonian.

It's already known that if $G$ and $H$ are Hamiltonian then $G \square  H$ is also Hamiltonian.

Therefore it follows that $Q_{n+1}$ = $Q_n \square  K_2$ is Hamiltonian.

Hence it follows that, for all $n \geq 2$, the $Q_n$ is Hamiltonian.